# Platformer Collision in Pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I was trying to write a platformer in Pygame, but for the past few weeks I've been stuck on the collision detection between the hero and the platform. Here are my classes:

```
class Platform(object):
    def __init__(self, colour, rect):
        self.colour = colour
        self.rect = rect

    def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.colour, self.rect)


class Character(Block):
    def __init__(self, colour, rect, speed):
        super().__init__(colour, rect)
        (self.dx, self.dy) = speed
        self.is_falling = True

    def update(self, platforms):
        self.is_falling = True
        for platform in platforms:
            if self.is_on(platform):
                self.rect.bottom = platform.rect.top
                self.dy = 0
                self.is_falling = False

        if self.is_falling:
            self.gravity()
        self.rect.x += self.dx
        self.rect.y += self.dy

    def is_on(self, platform):
        return (pygame.Rect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + self.dy,
                            self.rect.width, self.rect.height)
                .colliderect(platform.rect) and self.dy > 0)

    def left(self):
        self.dx = -5

    def right(self):
        self.dx = 5

    def stop_x(self):
        self.dx = 0

    def jump(self):
        if self.dy == 0:
            self.dy = -25

    def gravity(self):
        self.dy += 5
```

and here are my functions:

```
def key_down(event, character):
    if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
        character.left()
    elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
        character.right()
    elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
        character.jump()

def key_up(event, character):
    if event.key in (pygame.K_LEFT, pygame.K_RIGHT):
        character.stop_x()

def main():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
    pygame.display.set_caption("PyPlatformer")
    hero = Character((255, 255, 0), pygame.Rect(100, 0, 20, 20), (0, 0))
    platform1 = Block((0, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(100, 100, 100, 10))
    platform2 = Block((0, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(150, 150, 100, 10))
    platforms = (platform1, platform2)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    while True:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                key_down(event, hero)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                key_up(event, hero)

        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        hero.update(platforms)
        [platform.draw(screen) for platform in platforms]
        hero.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
```

However, when a `Character` is sitting on a `Block`, the collision detection fails, and the character falls through the block. However, when it is moving and inside the block, the detection succeeds and the character goes back to sitting on the block. This cycle then repeats and the character looks like it is bouncing on the block.

What is causing this bug? How do I fix it?

Comment: add many `print` with different values, slow down game to 2 FPS and observe printed text .

Answer (score 0):

This version works for me:

```
def is_on(self, platform):
    return (pygame.Rect(self.rect.x, self.rect.y + self.dy+1, # +1
                        self.rect.width, self.rect.height)
            .colliderect(platform.rect))
```

I add `+1` and remove `dy > 0`

---

By The Way: I found other problem.

If you put platforms too close (see `128` in `platform2`)

```
platform1 = Block((0, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(100, 100, 100, 10))
platform2 = Block((0, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(150, 128, 100, 10)) # 128
```

player standing on `platform2` can touch `platform1` and he is moved on `platform1`

It can move me realy high :)

```
platforms = []
platforms.append(Block((0, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(100, 400, 100, 10)))
platforms.append(Block((0, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(150, 428, 100, 10)))
platforms.append(Block((0, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(250, 28, 10, 400)))
```

Comment: Instead of removing `dy > 0`, I added `dy >= 0`

Comment: I made it as first but didn't help - only `+1` in `self.rect.y + self.dy + 1` in detection work for me.

Comment: But I found other problem - I jumped from high wall and I didn't stop on floor - gravity was big so I moved too fast to detect floor :)

Comment: I've fixed the problem with close platforms, but I'm still trying to work out the gravity problem. I think I will write my own collision detection, unless you can think of a better solution ;)

Comment: You have to get rectangle from old positon to new positon and check collision. But this give another problem - what if you first check collision with lower platform and you move player but there was higher platform on player way. First You have to check collision with all platforms and than you have to find which one is nearer to player. Maybe you could use `pygame.sprite.Group()`, `pygame.sprite.spritecollideany()`, `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` - see [Sprite](http://pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) docs.